# Atributo em DataAnotation para Currency

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, atributos, dataannotations

Gostaria de formatar com DataAnnotation currency mas padrão pt-br

na model:

```
[Column("cur_mensalidade")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C0}")]
public decimal? Mensalidade { get; set; }
```

porém não aceita o vírgula. mesmo no web.config colocando

```
 <system.web>
    <globalization uiCulture="pt" culture="pt-BR" enableClientBasedCulture="false" />
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei criar uma expressão regular, para formatar

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+(\.|\,)\d{2}$", ErrorMessage = "{0} valor incorreto.")]
```

Comment: Você se refere a vírgula referente as "moedas"?

Comment: isso. está em um padrão us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acordo com a imagem, quem está validando o input é o browser, e não seu app. Veja e ele não criou um `<input type="number" />`. Pois se for isso, fica fora de seu controle a formatação, pois vai depender da cultura do browser, e talvez do Windows.

No caso, você terá que criar manualmente o HTML do campo de input, como `<input type="text" />` e então formatar isso em outra maneira - javascript ou no backend, como preferir.

Já usei algumas vezes o [jQuery MKoneyMask](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney). Uma lib jQuery feita por um brazuca. Dá um bizú e veja se resolve sua necessidade.

Comment: se eu coloco o padrão decimal como fazer para ele não mudar para o type=number

Comment: @Dorathoto, Na View, basta vc não usar o Html Helper.

Comment: Thiago, @Dorathoto só lembrando que você pode sobrescrever o `Html Helper` com o que deseja, como por exemplo: `@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Question, new {@class="form-control", @data_val="false", @type="password"})`. [Exemplo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xRmnop)

Answer (score 5):

Você pode implementar um `ModelBinder` para isso.

```
public class DecimalModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext,
                                     ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        object result = null;

        // Don't do this here!
        // It might do bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError
        // and there is no RemoveModelError!
        // 
        // result = base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);

        string modelName = bindingContext.ModelName;
        string attemptedValue =
            bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(modelName).AttemptedValue;

        // Depending on CultureInfo, the NumberDecimalSeparator can be "," or "."
        // Both "." and "," should be accepted, but aren't.
        string wantedSeperator = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator;
        string alternateSeperator = (wantedSeperator == "," ? "." : ",");

        if (attemptedValue.IndexOf(wantedSeperator) == -1
            && attemptedValue.IndexOf(alternateSeperator) != -1)
        {
            attemptedValue =
                attemptedValue.Replace(alternateSeperator, wantedSeperator);
        }

        try
        {
            if (bindingContext.ModelMetadata.IsNullableValueType
                && string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attemptedValue))
            {
                return null;
            }

            result = decimal.Parse(attemptedValue, NumberStyles.Any);
        }
        catch (FormatException e)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(modelName, e);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

E em seu `Global.asax` no `Application_Start()` basta adicionar o `DecimalModelBinder`:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal), new DecimalModelBinder());
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(decimal?), new DecimalModelBinder());
```

Referências:

- [How to set decimal separators in ASP.NET MVC controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5117441/4843158)
- [Accept comma and dot as decimal separator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17716664/4843158)

Comment: entendi, mas caramba não existe algo mais simples tipo um dataannotations? uma expressão regular?

Comment: @Dorathoto Você pode criar um attributo novo para fazer essa validação, que daria quase no mesmo. Dessa forma você cria apenas uma vez e vale para todos os campos.

Comment: crio essa classe public class DecimalModelBinder?

Comment: @Dorathoto Exatamente

Comment: Erro CS1503 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'WMB.Bibliotecas.DecimalModelBinder' to 'System.Web.ModelBinding.IModelBinder' Global.asax.cs 21|

Comment: Você está utilizando a referência do `System.Web.ModelBinding.IModelBinder`, e não do seu projeto. Modifique o `using ...` que funcionará.  Lembrando que isso é para o servidor, se quiser modificar a validação no `client` também, deverá ver a outra resposta também.

Answer (score 1):

Essa validação deve estar sendo feita via jquery.
Crie um arquivo jquery.validade.ptBr.js

```
$.validator.methods.range = function (value, element, param) {
var globalizedValue = value.replace(",", ".");
return this.optional(element) || (globalizedValue >= param[0] && globalizedValue <= param[1]);}$.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) { return this.optional(element) || /^-?(?:\d+|\d{1,3}(?:[\s\.,]\d{3})+)(?:[\.,]\d+)?$/.test(value);}
```

E coloque na view.
No dataannotation, como o globalization já ta setado para pt-br nem precisa colocar todas essas informações, eu só deixo como decimal? e funciona.

Mas no seu caso, o problema é na validação no client nem chega a entrar no controller. Por isso tem que resolver o javascript.