# Data Annotation com Valores em Real

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Eu tenho o seguinte `model`:

```
[Display(Name = "Valor")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public decimal Valor { get; set; }
```

`View`:

```
<div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Valor, "Valor", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
  <div class="input-group">
     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-money"></i></span>
     @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Valor, new {htmlAttributes=new {@class="money form-control"}})
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Valor, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

No web.config tem a seguinte configuração:

```
 <system.web>

 <globalization culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR" />

 </system.web>
```

Ao fazer o post o ModelState.IsValid apresenta o seguinte erro:

> The value '1.500,00' is not valid for Valor.

Comment: O que você chama de "não funciona"? O que acontece e o que você espera?

Comment: Quando coloco valores com milhar como 1.500,00 o datamodel.isvalid retorna false e informa que o valor não é válido.

Comment: Provavelmente você deve encontrar o que deseja nas respostas [desta pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/126500/20615).